# Button background image disappears when I change from portrait mode to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've inserted a background image to my button, to make it look neat.

But when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape mode the background image of the button disappears.

Attached images for reference.

[image: ButtonBackgroundPortrait]

[image: ButtonBackgroundLandscape]

Comment: add the code that you use

Comment: did you check the width of button in landscape mode?

Comment: you need to add the code u used for button background

Comment: How do I check the width for landscape mode?

Comment: Also... How to implement the code exactly without getting any errors :)

Comment: @ibrahimbajnaid I have updated the answer to give you a solution, it is an autolayout problem, not with setting the background image

Comment: @ibrahimbajnaid any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is that the button gets pressed into `height = 0` because you have these two constraints upon the button:

```
clickHere.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
```

and

```
clickHere.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 304)
```

In landscape the centerY of button is closer to bottom than 304 + buttonHeight, therefore autolayout presses the button to height = 0 to as close to fulfilling constraints as possible. Since the height of the button is set by intrinsic size of the button, its priority is lower than the priority of your constraints.

In your case the solution is very simple, just delete the second constraint:

```
clickHere.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 304)
```

It's the one that in your screenshot of storyboards is at the bottom in the list of constraints, and its name is

> Bottom Layout Guide.top = Click Here.bottom + 304